# What do you call for a person who submits an application for a student?

Tags: single-word-requests

We have agents, student and parent who can submit an application for a student. Wondering whether I could call them applicant?

Comment: The "applicant" would only be the student herself.  Others submitting an application on her behalf are not called  the "applicant".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of a word specific to student applications. But, a person that is officially taking action on behalf of another could be referred to as a ***proxy***:

> **1.1** A person authorized to act on behalf of another.
>   <sub>[Oxford *Living* Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/proxy)</sub>